# Weird Java Exception Behaviour

Tags: java, google-app-engine, exception, google-cloud-endpoints

I am using Google App Engine with Cloud Endpoints.
I have noticed a weird thing in Java exception handling in it.

Consider this exception stack

```
com.google.api.server.spi.response.ForbiddenException: Unable to find an organization(4)-user(1) match.
    at com.fms.advocacy.api.auth.JwtUser.getUserFromRequest(JwtUser.java:172)
    at com.fms.advocacy.api.user_profile.UserProfileApi.getCurrentUserProfile(UserProfileApi.java:150)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.invoke(Runtime.java:130)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemService.invokeServiceMethod(SystemService.java:363)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet.execute(SystemServiceServlet.java:113)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet.doPost(SystemServiceServlet.java:71)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.fms.advocacy.filters.AccessRuleFilter.doFilter(AccessRuleFilter.java:67)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.fms.advocacy.filters.AuthFilter.doFilter(AuthFilter.java:48)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.fms.advocacy.filters.CorsFilter.doFilter(CorsFilter.java:27)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.fms.advocacy.filters.ErrorHandlerFilter.doFilter(ErrorHandlerFilter.java:38)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.api.socket.dev.DevSocketFilter.doFilter(DevSocketFilter.java:74)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
```

Here the exception is thrown by getUserFromRequest method.
As you can see, it is chained from the filters ErrorHandlerFilter > CorsFilter > AuthFilter > AccessRuleFilter.

In ErrorHandlerFilter filter I wrote a code like,

```
 public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        try { 
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        } catch (Throwable throwable) { 
            System.out.println("Got " + throwable.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

So ideally, the client should not receive anything, and the message should print in my console. But both are not happening. instead the client received the following response.

```
{
  "error" : {
    "message" : "Unable to find an organization(4)-user(1) match.",
    "code" : 403,
    "errors" : [ {
      "domain" : "global",
      "reason" : "forbidden",
      "message" : "Unable to find an organization(4)-user(1) match."
    } ]
  }
}
```

Why is it like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception thrown is caught before it gets to your catch clause in  `ErrorHandlerFilter`.

I'm not familiar with google-app-engine, but I suppose it's done by `com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet`, since exception is nicely wrapped in json and is not propagated furher.

So, from the `ErrorHandlerFilter.doFilter()` method's point of view, everything went fine. When `chain.doFilter(request, response);` returns, json with is written to `response`'s output stream already.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. May be that is what they are doing.